# How to append multiple rows to csv file using python

Tags: python, csv, append, row

Im trying to append user inputted data to rows , however im having no luck.

Counter is a user defined global variable which i have created elsewhere in the code.

when the data is appended, instead of moving to another line it just rewrites the same line over and over and as a new user of python i have no idea what im doing wrong.

```
def AppendCsv(): 
    NumberOfNamesToBeAdded()
    with open ('Graph.csv', 'a') as graphFile:
        graphFileWriter=csv.writer(graphFile)
        for x in counter:
             graphFileWriter.writerow([ID, Name,Cost,Date1])
```

Comment: What is ID, Name, Cost and Date1? Do they change on these loops?

Comment: When you say it rewrites the same line over and over, do you mean it overwrites the same line and you end up only appending a single new row to the CSV? Or do you mean that the same row is appended multiple times?

Comment: I mean that the same row is overwritten, so only 1 row ends up being appended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what's in `counter`, for one thing. With a `range` in `counter`, like this:

```
import csv

counter = range(3)

with open('Graph.csv', 'a', newline='') as graphFile:
    graphFileWriter = csv.writer(graphFile)
    for x in counter:
        graphFileWriter.writerow([1,2,3])
```

the result is this:

```
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
```

You might also want to insert `, newline=''` in the `open` statement.

Comment: counter is a string , so if i just change it to 
    counter=range(input('enter the number'))
this should work?

Comment: I expect so, yes.